# I want sql query from php if value null then insert else exit

Tags: php, sql, authentication

```
function validate_user($email   =   '' , $password   =  '', $deviceid = ''){
    $result = FALSE;
    $credential    =   array(  'email' => $email , 'password' => $password );
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user' , $credential);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0):
        $this->db->where($credential);
        
       if
      ($this->db->where('user' array('token' => IS NULL )));
     $this->db->update('user', array('token' => $deviceid ));
    
       
        
    
       
        $result = TRUE;
    endif;    
    return $result;      
}
```

here is my code i get error on line 7 where i check its null or not.
and if this null i want add device id else if have vale in token exit

Comment: What is `$this->db`? How does it work? You need to quote `IS NULL`, this is not valid PHP syntax.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by putting `WHERE` clause in `if` statement? Please get your basics clarified first then ask a proper question.

Comment: i dont know properly thats why i am here .... i want insert token if is this null if not null then no need to update

Comment: We can't help you debug an unknown library. So what exactly are you using? Is it a framework? Just a DB library?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky to give a definitive answer, when it is unclear what kind of object 'db' is, but I would guess your problem is on this line:

```
($this->db->where('user' array('token' => IS NULL )));
```

I would suggest you remove the 'IS' from there, so the line would be

```
($this->db->where('user' array('token' => NULL)));
```

If this does not help, please expand your question a bit by adding more information of what DB library you are using.

Comment: _"It is a bit tricky to give a definitive answer, when it is unclear what kind of object 'db' is"_ - you are right about this. That's why unclear questions should not be answered. It's best to wait for clarification from the OP to avoid guesswork and causing potential duplicate content. If it truly boils down to a simple syntax error, then the question should be closed. Don't get me wrong, it's good to see that you want to contribute, but you should focus your efforts on worthy questions.

Comment: this was update all filed if null also insert if not null then also update   ,, i only need to insert when its null if notnull then exit

Answer (score 0):

simple syntax error

```php
$this->db->where('user',array('token' => NULL ))
```

Comment: And you are certain this will work because...? Do you recognize the DB library that is used here? If so, please add an explanation. On the other end, if you just wanted to clear the syntax error, we don't answer that type of question because it holds no long term value. There's a canonical question that covers all the general cases that we use as a duplicate target.